# How can i return a pointer to char[][][] from function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, declaration, function-declaration

I have a `static`-char array defined as:

```c
static const char city_names[1000][4][50];
```

And i want to return a pointer to this variable from functions, i try a `static_cast` to `void*` but it fail. How can i return a pointer to `char[][][]` ?

Comment: `using array_1000_4_50 = char const[1000][4][50]; array_1000_4_50* p = &city_names;`

Comment: In C++, it is not possible for a function to directly return a one-dimensional array, since a pointer is not actually an array. Things get worse with additional dimensions - e.g. a pointer to pointer (e.g. `char **`) and a 2D array cannot be treated as equivalent *at all* unless you seek undefined behaviour. Instead of trying to return a raw array, use standard containers (e.g. a `std::vector` can contain `std::vector`s to get multiple dimensions). If dimension are fixed at compile time, you can use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`

Comment: @Peter, I tried `std::vector` but it result in long compile time.

Comment: @Eljay, And how can i returned from function ?

Comment: You can return the pointer from a function like:  `auto GetCityNames() { return &city_names; }`

Comment: @GhasemRamezani - That probably means you're using it wrong, but you haven't provided any information on what you actually did to get long compilation times.  With modern compilers, you'd have to do something pretty dramatic to get long compilation times with nested `std::vector`s - or be using a VERY old compiler on very old hardware.

Comment: @Peter, I use that variable as a little static database to my program. And when i use `const std::vector<std::vector<string>>` instead of `const char[1000][4][50]` and start compilation, it take a long time (about 30s) to done. I have a __Dell latitude E6410__.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer to the array (more precisely to the first element of the array if you will initialize it with the array) can be declared like

```
static const char city_names[1000][4][50];

const char ( *p )[4][50] = city_names;
```

So a function declaration that returns such a pointer can look like

```
const char ( *f( /* some parameters */ ) )[4][50];
```

And within the function you may just write

```
return city_names;
```

That is if you have an array declared like

```
T a[N1][N2][N3];
```

where T is some type specifier and N1, N2, N3 are constants that specify sizes of the array then you may rewrite the declaration like

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2][N3];
```

To get a pointer to the element type of the array just substitute the record ( a[N1] ) for a declarator of pointer like

```
T ( *p )[N2][N3] = a;
```

Comment: I think "to the first element of the array" is less precisely, on the language level. +1, though

Comment: And where is explanation of 'how to declare of those types' ?

Comment: @GhasemRamezani I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I mean where do you read about how to define those types ?

Comment: @GhasemRamezani It is just my personal fantasies.